# ¿Como insertar texto a un archivo en una linea determinada?

Tags: linux, bash

*Bien les resumire algo simple, nesesito agregar lineas a partir de una linea determinada, les comento basicamente que pretendo hacer, quiero armar un script bash que inserte codigo a un archivo de configuracion de wordpress.. por ejemplo si utilizo la instruccion echo solo me la coloca al final del archivo.. pero nesesito especificar a partir de que linea colocar el codigo. eso era mi duda gracias*

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: creo que mi pregunta es entendible mas haya que aun no conozca las reglas del sitio, me parece que si no sabes la respuesta a mi pregunta simplemente puedes no contestar, igual agradezco tu respuesta aunque no me sea util.

Comment: Tu pregunta es entendible, tal vez, pero no sigue las normas y recomendaciones para recibir una respuesta efectiva. Pedir que alguien haga algo sin indicar qué has intentado y por qué falló, suele terminar con la respuesta cerrada. Y no te confundas, que estos comentarios que te dejo no son una respuesta y sólo busco que no te cierren la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

En Linux básicamente hay dos programas para eso, `awk` y `sed`. Deberías identificar como determinar a donde poner el texto. Como básicos, yo te pongo ejemplos de añadir texto en linea conocida, o a patrón conocido. Pero hay muchas opciones mas.

#### Sed o Awk

Ambos son  herramientas muy potentes pero con formas de trabajo distinto. En `sed`, la corba de aprendizaje es mas baja, así que de ese van los ejemplos.

La respuesta esta al nivel de la especificación de la pregunta, te pongo unos ejemplos genéricos básicos. Para mas detalle puedes buscar por internet manuales y ejemplos, o hacer una pregunta mas especifica si no encuentras solución a tus necesidades.

#### Diferencias de conceptos: Insert y Append

Antes que nada, mencionar un concepto tipico en los sistemas Linux y programación:  `INSERT` hace referencia a insertar en la misma linea identificada, y `APPEND` hace referencia en añadir después de la identificación.

La opción `a` que vas a ver a continuación hace referencia en `append`. Cámbiala por `i` si lo que necesitas un `insert`. Hago los ejemplos con `append`.

#### Ejemplos de soluciones

*Si quieres editar ficheros directamente utiliza la opción `-i`. Quitala para que el output se muestra en consola sin editar el fichero original ( ideal para pruebas).*

#### añadir texto en linea conocida

Añadimos Hola en linea 20

`sed '20 a Hola' -i fichero.txt`

#### añadir en la linea siguiente de un patrón conocido

El patrón es una expresión regular. En este caso añadiria Hola en las siguientes lineas que encontrara patron.

`sed '/patron/ a Hola' -i fichero.txt`

No dudes en seguir investigando, comentar o a realizar nuevas preguntas si no encuentras respuestas.